# 'vector' file not found in one xcode project, but not in other

Tags: ios, xcode, vector, stdvector

I am trying to use vectors in xcode, but it's not working in my current project. I get the error message  `'vector' file not found.` I have already added `#include < vector >`
and changed the file from .m to .mm . "The compile source as" is set to "According To File Type" and I've tried both Compilers (4.1 and GCC 4.2). I've also cleaned the project but no luck.

I made a new project and did those steps and vector works completely fine. I've even taken the same file and put it in the new project and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces between the brackets.  I.e.,

```
#include <vector>
```

not

```
#include < vector >
```

Comment: That's actually how it is in the code, I was just having formatting problems with the question

Comment: Okay.  Then I'd suggest you'll have to look at the Build Settings.  Something must be different.  Maybe the compiler setting "Compiler for C/C++/Objective C"?

Comment: Those are set to "Default Compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 4.1)". I've tried the two compilers shown, and neither of them make a difference. I've also looked through the build settings a couple of times, and haven't found any differences. It is possibly that i was using an earlier version of xcode at the time, and maybe that's causing problems?

Comment: I'm not sure what else it could be.  I bet you fixed it when you changed it to .mm and maybe you're confused about the series of events?  I'm just guessing now.